# Rails good practice in generating controllers , models and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

In rails, which is the best practice to create Models, Controllers and Views? There are three ways I am aware of.

1) Scaffolding "everything".

2) Generating each Controller and Model via terminal.

3) Manually creating all files. (Need to be careful when doing this. I have to keep in mind about pluralizing Controller and using singular in Model)

Currently, I follow third method though it involves a bit of risk. I just want to know what is the best practice to follow. And if there are any other ways, I would be glad to know. Thanks for your time.

P.S : I am a beginner in RoR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think scaffolding is rather bad because it generates a lot of stuff you probably don't want, I only use it for spike solutions.

In real projects my company rule book says that I have to use Test Driven Development (which I do like). Meaning that in a default approach (which sometimes I can't manage to follow) I start with an integration test and follow from it. (I build a route then a controller method then a view then a model...).

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that scaffolding is best approach as it automates the whole process of manual creation. You will get your model, controller, views and migrations by just a `rails g scaffold myscaffold` and that is why we call ruby on rails as agile web development solutions.
So tools which support the developers to rapidly bootstrap a software or change functionalities rapidly help you in being agile.

Another thing is if you may bootstrap a project rapidly you may react on reordering of priorities more flexible. This will help in core development of your developing plans at 
a more clear and better way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect solution. If you code by hand, are you really using idiomatic rails? 
For the "intermediate" programmers - that neither want to code everything by hand, nor can rely on simple scaffolding. You MUST understand generated code, but leave 60 wpm perfect coding from scratch to the gurus!

I suggest three pragmatics

A. GET A GREAT START. Boilerplating is the major way to do it in Javascript and Node projects where you select the modules you want (devise for auth, simple_form for ajaxy forms, twitter-bootstrap etc) and you START WITH a fairly loaded site, instead of bolting it on piecemeal. This is not heavy - just for making "PRO" sites. I am still looking for good RoR boiler plates, railsapps (composer is sister site), and railsbricks, as well as the good old Rails templates, Rails Engines should allow you to do this. Sadly, not enough coverage of how this is done as it requires "gurus" to provide tested configurations that incorporate best practices.

B. MODEL-FIRST APPROACH. Start with a decent model from day one. Instead of adding fields one by one, sit down and try to get 3-4 core tables for your site and their relationships worked out. The "agile" people might argue against minimalist approach, but if you are experienced, why not "design it a bit ahead". Of course you want to avoid the other extreme of 10s of tables or ER diagrams before coding! If you have decent mockups/User designs, you can project the look of site and inherent models fairly well in advance for your MVP (minimally viable product). This of course suggests you have ~2-4 weeks foresight on what you want the app to look like:)

C. TEST/MIGRATION LESS SCAFFOLDING. A hybrid approach is more practical where you first do the model generation and any data migrations alone, then scaffold WITHOUT test or migrations with the options. You can see the Rails 4 for Beginners book ch 5 for an example of this. Benefit is - you don't overwrite the hand crafted models code and let scaffolding take care of dirty details of the ~5+ files per model that the RoR magic gives you.
    # 1. generate model Article with title, body
    #    do rake db:create,  manually add validation eg presence, minimal lengths etc to Model
    # You can do a scaffold here ..
    # Now add location and excerpt by db migration ONLY (not manual schema edit nor scaffold all)
    $ rails generate migration add_excerpt_and_location_to_articles
excerpt:string location:string
    # now OVERWRITE SCAFFOLD but not model ..
    $ rails g scaffold Article title:string location:string excerpt:string
body:text published_at:datetime --skip-migration

If you get the point - you can see that SCAFFOLDING IS TREATED AS THROW-AWAY as you evolve your models. You really don't care anything about overwriting the controller details nor views at this time. But you are PROTECTING your models, and hand edits e.g. relationships between models, and detailed validations.

As a side-benefit, the model-first pragmatic works well with this approach. You can get pretty darn far to 5-20 models in your app before you stop scaffolding. By that time, your code models should be fairly determined.